# How do I set fields in a model in Django before validation?

Tags: django

I need to set some fields in a Django model, before validations, on save, based on other fields in the object model. They are fields that might be entered manually, but if they are not, they should be generated from other fields and when they are, they might require further modification. Once they are set they can evolve separatedly.

A good proxy, or simples possible example, for what I'm trying to achieve would be to have `first_name`, `last_name`, and `full_name`. If `full_name` is not provided when created or blanked when updating, I want to *recalculate* it from `first_name` and `last_name`.

I tried doing something like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=100)
    full_name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=200)

    def clean_fields(self, exclude=None):
        if not self.full_name and self.first_name and self.last_name:
            self.full_name = self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
        return super(Person, self).clean_fields(exclude)
```

When I try to save the object in the admin tool, `full_name` is successfully set (I can see it in the debugger), but I still get the `full_name` is blank validation error and when the form is generated again, the generated fields remain blank.

What's the correct way of populating `full_name` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of doing it on `clean_fields` you could override `save` ? Almost exactly your code from `clean_fields` should still work -

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.full_name and self.first_name and self.last_name:
            self.full_name = self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

However, I'd recommend not having `full_name` be its own field - it is duplicated data in your db, and now you have to worry about full name and first & last getting out of sync. What happens if full name is NOT empty but they change first or last - wouldn't you still want to change full name then?

Instead, why not use a property?

```
@property
def full_name(self):
    return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
```

A setter is optional - I personally don't include setters and force updates to happen only in first and last name fields because of difficulty in dealing with names like "Victor von Doom" - but you could take a stab at it with something like

```
@setter.full_name
def full_name(self, new_val):
    names = new_val.split()
    self.first_name = names[0]
    self.last_name = " ".join(names[1:])
```

Comment: This is only an example, my problem is much more complex than this. It's fields that sometimes can be calculated and sometimes it can and they are entered manually, soetimes they are calculated and need further modification. If I do it in save as you said, the validation will fail.

Comment: To answer your question, in my actual code, the fields are allowed to evolve completely separated, but for most cases, generating one from the others is a good first approximation.